# Is there something similar to pdf dev.off() for shapefiles using R

Tags: r, shapefile

Is there something similar to

```
pdf(...)
plot commands
...
...
dev.off()
```

for shapefiles ??

I´d like to save the final plot figure with shapes+points+legend for further overlaying on other map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be no R system that could parse the pdf file or even do editing to a pdf file. I suppose you could call `system()` with an ImageMagick call but that would be kind of ridiculous.. You need to use either `lattice` or `ggplot2` when you want to do incremental additions to an R plot object ... before file creation. You would be able to create an .eps file using the `postscript()` device and if it had a transparent background you should be able to use the result as an overlay.

Comment: Thanks @DWin, but what I want is to save as a Shapefile (.shp) the final result of a plot. Usually when I want to plot a shapefile I use plot(shape) then I could add other plots(shp2, ad=TRUE), plus points, Legends etc. Is it possible to convert this final figure to a Shapefile and save it?

Comment: You do not seem to understand that the final result of a plot call will NOT be a shapefile even if the chosen plot system returns an object. There are plot methods for shapefiles, but any additions using the coordinate systems should be done before plotting, or use a plotting system (ggplot2 or lattice) that 'understands' your coordinates and can add to an existing plot object of class "gglot" or "trellis" (before printing it again).

Answer (score 0):

This is not how shapefiles work. You cannot combine more than one geometry in a shapefile. So, you can have a point shapefile, a line shapefile,  or  a polygon shapefile, but not a combination of these.

To save a particular layer as a shapefile, you could use `writeOGR(...)` in package `rgdal`. But then you would have to combine the layers later using a GIS program.

Finally, the kml specification does allow multiple geometries in a single kml file, but there is no way in R (that I am aware of) to create such a kml file. On the other hand, since kml is an XML vocabulary, you might be able to write a program to combine all the geometries into a single kml file that way.

Comment: Thankful @jlhoward, I get to save the layers of points, lines and polygons in a single file is feasible, but the plot function is capable of generating other objects such as Legend. Is it possible to convert the Legend on something similar to list of SpatialPolygons and save them to a shapefile as a layer?